# Is there any option to list groups in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

As far as i know, ansible has an option named `--list-hosts` for listing hosts. Is there any option for listing host groups? Or any other way to come through?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can simply inspect the `groups` variable using the `debug` module:

```
ansible localhost -m debug -a 'var=groups.keys()'
```

The above is using `groups.keys()` to get just the list of groups. You could drop the `.keys()` part to see group membership as well:

```
ansible localhost -m debug -a 'var=groups'
```

Comment: Also `ansible-inventory -i inventory/prod.yml --list`

Comment: Using `ansible-inventory -i inventory/prod.yml --list` will list the whole inventory structure, nothing filtered or selected

Answer (score 15):

### Listing groups

Using tools built-in to Ansible + [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq), this gives you something reasonably close:

```
ansible-inventory --list | jq "keys"
```

An advantage of this approach vs manually parsing inventory files is that it fully utilizes your `ansible.cfg` files (which can point to one or multiple inventory files, a directory of inventory files, etc...).

Example output on my machine (`local_redis_all` is a locally defined Ansible group):

```json
[
  "_meta",
  "all",
  "local_redis_all",
]
```

If you prefer it in plain-text form, use an approach like `ansible-inventory --list | jq -r "keys | .[]"`. It will give you an output like this:

```
_meta
all
local_redis_all
```

#### Listing hosts

This was not part of the original question, but including it here anyway since it might be useful to some of my readers. Use the following command for JSON output (note: the command actually outputs a JSON array for each group, I haven't yet figured out a way to flatten these with `jq` - suggestions are welcome):

`ansible-inventory --list | jq ".[].hosts | map(.)?`

This gives you an output similar to this:

```json
[
  "redis-01",
  "redis-02",
  "redis-03"
]
```

Likewise, in raw text format (one host per line): `ansible-inventory --list | jq -r ".[].hosts | .[]?"`

This gives you an output like this:

```
redis-01
redis-02
redis-03
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now.

Answer (score 10):

> **Note:- For New Ansible Users**

Ansible has some special internal variables which are also known as Magic Variables.

From this link you will get full list of magic variables [Magic Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html)

There is magic variable called "groups" which hold the inventory group information.
we can access the value of any variable ( both user defined and Internal ) using an ansible module called **debug** .

> **I am Using Separate Inventory File**

```
$
$ ansible -i inventory.ini all -m debug -a "var=groups" 
$
centos-client.ansible.lab | SUCCESS => {
    "groups": {
        "all": [
            "centos-client.ansible.lab", 
            "ubuntu-client.ansible.lab"
        ], 
        "centos": [
            "centos-client.ansible.lab"
        ], 
        "ubuntu": [
            "ubuntu-client.ansible.lab"
        ], 
        "ungrouped": []
    }
}
ubuntu-client.ansible.lab | SUCCESS => {
    "groups": {
        "all": [
            "centos-client.ansible.lab", 
            "ubuntu-client.ansible.lab"
        ], 
        "centos": [
            "centos-client.ansible.lab"
        ], 
        "ubuntu": [
            "ubuntu-client.ansible.lab"
        ], 
        "ungrouped": []
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the best answer. Magic variables are the way to go. I attended DO407 of Redhat training and I am confirming this answer.

Answer (score 5):

#### Method #1 - Using Ansible

If you just want a list of the groups within a given inventory file you can use the [magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) as mentioned in a couple of the other answers.

In this case you can use the `groups` magic variable and specifically just show the `keys()` in this hash (keys + values). The keys are all the names of the groups.

**NOTE:** By targeting the `localhost` we force this command to just run against a single host when processing the inventory file.

```
$ ansible -i inventory/rhvh localhost -m debug -a 'var=groups.keys()'
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "groups.keys()": "dict_keys(['all', 'ungrouped', 'dc1-rhvh', 'dc2-rhvh', 'dc3-rhvh', 'dc4-rhvh', 'dc5-rhvh', 'rhvh', 'dc1', 'dc2', 'dc3', 'dc4', 'dc5', 'production'])"
}
```

#### Method #2 - using `grep` & `sed`

You could of course just `grep` the contents of your inventory file too:

```
$ grep -E '^\[' inventory/rhvh
[dc1-rhvh]
[dc2-rhvh]
[dc3-rhvh]
[dc4-rhvh]
[dc5-rhvh]
[rhvh:children]
[dc1:children]
[dc2:children]
[dc3:children]
[dc4:children]
[dc5:children]
[production:children]
```

You're on the hook though for teasing out of the 2nd method's output or you can use `sed` to do it:

```
$ grep -E '^\[' inventory/rhvh | sed 's/:children//'
[dc1-rhvh]
[dc2-rhvh]
[dc3-rhvh]
[dc4-rhvh]
[dc5-rhvh]
[rhvh]
[dc1]
[dc2]
[dc3]
[dc4]
[dc5]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're not sure if the host will actually be in the inventory you can use:

```
ansible -i hosts/ localhost -m debug -a 'var=groups'
```

`-i`  where your inventory files are kept
`-m`  enable module debug.
`-a`  module arguments.

It will output the group / hosts just once and not for every host in your inventory.

Same goes for just getting the list of groups in the inventory:

```
ansible -i hosts/ localhost -m debug -a 'var=groups.keys()'
```

Answer (score 0):

another way to see your hosts is just to press `tab` after the `ansible` keyword.[image]

Answer (score -4):

Something like that?
`cat ~/inventory/* | grep "\[.*\]"`

Comment: Inventories can be defined as ini/yaml/json in static files or as dynamic executable scripts... so this regexp will fail in many cases.