# Select subscripts from children sub group

Tags: python, ansible, substring

Is it possible to subscripts children sub group?

Inventory file `testinv.ini`

```
[group1]
hostname1
hostname2
hostname3

[group2]
hostname4
hostname5
hostname6

[test:children]
group1[0:1]
group2[0:1]
```

`ansible -i testinv.ini --list-host test`

Running the list-host does not return any data.
Is it possible to match two hosts from every group under the children's group?

Expected result is:

```
hosts (4):
    hostname1
    hostname2
    hostname4
    hostname5
```

Answer (score 1):

According the documentation [Adding ranges of hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#adding-ranges-of-hosts) not, since it seems to be for hosts only.

As well a test with the provided inventory file `hosts` will result into an output and error message of

```bash
ansible-inventory -i hosts --graph
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse hosts with yaml plugin: We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each: JSON: 
No JSON object could be decoded  Syntax Error while loading YAML.   did not find expected <document start>  The error appears to be in 'hosts': 
line 2, column 1, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.  The offending line appears to be:  [group1] hostname1 ^ here 
[WARNING]:  * Failed to parse hosts with ini plugin: hosts:12: Expected group name, got: group1[0:1]
```

> *Is it possible to match 2 hosts from every group ...*

So, you would either need to create separate groups for, or limit the execution to certain hosts or group members.

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible - How to launch playbook only on the first (annot.: or even two) host(s) of each inventory group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73944342/)